# C# I cant connect to mysql database on my server :(

Tags: c#, mysql

I've never really done anything server sided so this is a first for me, this works with my wamp localhost server but clients will not be able to connect if my PC isn't on.

I have an [OVH server](http://prntscr.com/8r6dur) which also has wamp on it but I'm having problems connecting to it from my C# program.
(The ovh is not in my house(ie not lan))

Connection:

```
MySqlConnection Connection = new MySqlConnection("Server=149.202.60.45;Port=1433;Database=xps;Uid=*****;Password=*********;");
```

I've tried searching online for the past 2 hours but nothing works.

Comment: Is the webserver set to listen on the external port? Are there any firewalls between your client and your server that may be blocking connections?

Comment: Can you telnet to 149.202.60.45 on port 1433 from the server your c# application is hosted on?

Comment: Oh... I just checked my ports and they're closed -.- thanks guys, you never cease to disappoint :]